# Why is my string.split() function producing unexpected results?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, file-io, split

I have an input file consisting of:

```
1a 2a 2b 2c 2d 3a 3b 3c 3d
```

My Python code looks like:

```
f = open('access.txt', 'r')
controls = f.read()

for line in controls:
    s = line.split()
    print(s),
```

I expected an array in the format `['1a','2a','2b'b, ...]`. But what I get is a different format, and everything `print` twice:

```
['1'] ['a'] [] ['2'] ['a'] [] ['2'] ['b'] [] ['2'] ['c'] [] ['2'] ['d'] [] ['3'] ['a'] [] ['3'] ['b'] [] ['3'] ['c'] [] ['3'] ['d'] [] [] ['1'] ['a'] [] ['2'] ['a'] [] ['2'] ['b'] [] ['2'] ['c'] [] ['2'] ['d'] [] ['3'] ['a'] [] ['3'] ['b'] [] ['3'] ['c'] [] ['3'] ['d'] [] []
```

I can't seem to identify either problem.

**EDIT:** It looks like I was iterating character by character, which I've fixed.

Comment: If all the items are on a single line, just use `s = next(f).split()`

Comment: You should just drop the `f.read()` line and do `for line in f`

Comment: For the double printing: Are you 100% certain you're not running that code twice, because of code around it that you're not showing us?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this:

```
# automatically closes file when done
with open('access.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        s = line.split()
        print(s),
```

This way you are looping through line by line, and splitting each line individually.

Comment: Excellent, this works. I must have been iterating character by character as others mentioned. But what of the printing twice problem? 
`['1a', '2a', '2b', '2c', '2d', '3a', '3b', '3c', '3d'] ['1a', '2a', '2b', '2c', '2d', '3a', '3b', '3c', '3d']`

Comment: To be honest, I'm not sure. Maybe it's because it's the end of the day but I can't find a reason why it would be printing twice.

Comment: It's got to be some other part of the code. All I'm doing, though, is importing other classes. And I'm executing the code in terminal.

Comment: I agree. Is there any code around it that you could add to the question?

Answer (score 0):

Your for loop is looping through the entire file contents as a single string one character at a time. You can keep most of your code by doing something like this when you read the file:

```
controls = f.read().splitlines().
```

from there you can loop as you already do.

If your file is only one line, then you can just do:

```
f.read().split()
```

Comment: Hmm. I need to create a looping construct for the entire file, though. So how could I go about splitting lines? And what about the printing double?

Comment: So why don't just `f.readlines()` if you need split the file by lines?

Comment: I first assumed it was a multiline file :)

Comment: Actually, `controls = splitlines().splitlines()` is just errors: you weren't calling `splitlines()` _on_ anything (instead of on a string as required), and then you were calling it on what would have been a `list`. Oh, and you now have an extra `.` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a list of lines, use `readlines` instead of `read`.

Answer (score 0):

You may use readlines()

```
with open('data','r') as f:
    controls = f.readlines()

for line in controls:
    s = line.split()
    print(s, end=" "),

['1a', '2a', '2b', '2c', '2d', '3a', '3b', '3c', '3d']
```

Comment: For the love of everything, would you learn to correctly format a post?

Answer (score 0):

Because you're trying to use `for` on a string. Let's see:

```
f = open('access.txt', 'r')
controls = f.read()
```

Now what happened?  `controls` is a string because you're using `f.read()`.
So using `for` loop on a string will give something like...you can try it in Python Shell.

---

Actually you don't need `f.read()` here, the following code can works fine:

```
with open('access.txt', 'r') as f: # with can auto close the file, it's safe.    
    for line in f:
        s = line.split()
        print(s, end='')
```

---

Also, here is a simpler way that use *list comprehension* :

```
with open('access.txt', 'r') as f:
    print(*[s.split() for s in f])
```